# CSF / LFD picking up suspicious users in OpenVZ containers

Tags: openvz, csf

I have OpenVZ running on a box with CSF / LFD installed.

I like the way LFD can alert me of suspicious processes running on the HardwareNode itself.

However, LFD is emailing me about *every* suspicious process that the VE's are running.

Is there a way to make LFD ignore the /vz/root directory entirely?

Regards, 
Chris

Comment: attach alert, please

Comment: Feb  9 15:19:52 vza2 lfd[7835]: *User Processing* PID:8097 Kill:0 User: Time:2873 EXE:/var/lib/vz/root/3042/bin/dbus-daemon CMD:dbus-daemon --system

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak /etc/csf/csf.pignore (on the host) to your requirements.
In most cases we tend to ignore certain process on VMs like this:

```
exe:/var/lib/vz/root/*/usr/sbin/mysqld
exe:/var/lib/vz/root/*/usr/sbin/portmap
exe:/var/lib/vz/root/*/sbin/portmap
```